# pyodbc null datetime to None in Python3.7

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc4.0.30 with python3.7 on centos7. In my database(db2), I have datetime column which contains `null` value. This null value throws `ValueError` that I want to convert to None in python.
Let's say I have more than 50 datetime columns that have null value and I want to see them.

```py
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc('DSN=mydsn; UID=myid; PWD=mypwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from mydb.mytbl')
rows = cursor.fetchall() # this throws ValueError
```

So I am trying to handle it, if there is ValueError

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc('DSN=mydsn; UID=myid; PWD=mypwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
    sql = 'select * from mydb.mytbl'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
except ValueError:
    sql = 'select coalesce(column, None) from mydb.mytbl' # how can I find out the column which has null datetime
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

Is there any way not expensive to achieve this?

=======================================================
EDIT
I got this error

```
    print(cursor.fetchall())
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Comment: Can you post the exception with the full backtrace? I don't see anything here that would raise a ValueError.

Comment: @jordanm I edited.

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/475